# using "transform" in c++ gives an error that this was not declared in the scope

Tags: c++

I was converting a string to lowercase using transform and the compiler gives an error stating transform was not declared in the scope.

`transform(my_str.begin(), my_str.end(), my_str.begin(), ::tolower);`

Or tell me an alternative solution to solve this problem, thanks!

Comment: I am not allowed to use #include<algorithm> @greghewgill

Comment: Note that for using `std::tolower`, you need to include the header `<cctype>`. Are you allowed?

Comment: nope I am only restricted to add #include<iostream> and #include<string> @Damien

Comment: Well, if you can't include `<algorithm>` then you can't call `std::transform` from the standard library. Please, in the future, mention any arbitrary homework restrictions you have in your question *before* people start answering it.

Comment: And if you can't call `std::transform`, then you must be trying to implement your own version and your compiler is telling you that you haven't done so yet.

Comment: Sorry for that, I had no idea about that, but still if you can provide me with an alternative solution to this? @GregHewgill

Comment: If you can't use `tolower`, then I guess you will have to asssume a particular char encoding (ASCII ?).

Comment: @Damien Yes I had that in mind that I can also use ASCII but was unsure how would I use to convert string to lowercase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation for `transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform), this is a function in the `std` namespace. You will  have to include the correct header file, and qualify the function name:

```
#include <algorithm>

std::transform(my_str.begin(), my_str.end(), my_str.begin(), ::tolower);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use `transform` or `::tolower`, then you have to assume ASCII encoding, 
implement your own tolower and then use a `for` loop to convert the `string`.

```
#include    <iostream>
#include    <string>

char mytolower (char c) {
    constexpr int shift = 'A' - 'a';
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
        c -= shift;
    }
    return c;
}

int main () {
    std::string s = "sAcVZu";
    for (char &c: s) {
        c = mytolower (c);
    }
    std::cout << s;
}
```